# Tree Automorphism

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, automorphism-group

How can I get the automorphism group on a random tree? By a random tree I mean that I have a finite tree, but with a random progeny distribution.

Comment: You mean you're generating random trees, and want to find their automorphism groups? I would assume you'd use software that can calculate such things; what are you using to generate the trees? But if you mean probabilistic results for random trees, I have no idea.

Comment: I have a tree with a random number of children at each level. Is there some general result on the automorphism group on such trees? At any instance, I am looking at one particular sample tree. It is just that I have no idea of the specific degree distribution